# Calling unions of function types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, subtyping, structural-typing, union-types

In TypeScript 3.0.3, The following code will give a compile-time error:

```
function f() {
    if (true) {
        return (x: {left:String}) => x.left;
    } else {
        return (x: {right:String}) => x.right;
    }
}

class C {
    left: String = "";
    right: String = "";
}

f()(new C());
```

[code at typescriptlang.org](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20f()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(true)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(x%3A%20%7Bleft%3AString%7D)%20%3D%3E%20x.left%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(x%3A%20%7Bright%3AString%7D)%20%3D%3E%20x.right%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20left%3A%20String%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20right%3A%20String%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Af()(new%20C())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20g()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(x%3A%20%7Bleft%3AString%7D)%20%3D%3E%20x.left%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ag()(new%20C())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

I expected that the type of f would be `function f(): {left:String; right:String} => String` or equivalent one (for example, Scala typechecker reports a type like this).

However, I got the following type error:

```
./leftright.ts:17:1 - error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((x: { left: String; }) => String) | 
((x: { right: String; }) => String)' has no compatible call signatures.

17 f()(new C());
```

It seems that unions of function types are not directly callable, despite we can refer to a field in a union of object types.

Is there any way to modify `f()` to a callable one while preserving `if`-statement inside it?

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just annotate the return type of `f`, and the compiler will see that each of the functions you are returning is compatible with that type:

```
function f(): (x: { left: String, right: String }) => String {
    if (true) {
        return (x: {left:String}) => x.left;
    } else {
        return (x: {right:String}) => x.right;
    }
}
```